# Keyboard layout not recognized (Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've bought this TECKNET keyboard:

[image]

https://eu.tecknetonline.com/products/tecknet-x315-mini-wireless-keyboard-black-uk?_pos=1&_sid=cb6d2589e&_ss=r

Unfortunately, Ubuntu 20.04.3 does not automatically recognize the different layout, so that, for example, if I click "U" key, it gives "4"; in practice, all keys with FN values overlap the white ones, without pressing FN at all. In other threats I've read that I may use xev command to manually configure the new keyboard. However, is there a faster way?

Comment: what language is your keyboard made for? the layout should be fairly standard if you select the correct language.

Comment: I've bought on amazon italy; on product description it just says "QWERTY Italian"

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu **never** recognizes a keyboard layout. You always need to select the matching layout yourself, either during installation, or afterwards, in "Settings", "Keyboard", "Input sources".

The Ubuntu installer includes a tool that allows it to guess the keyboard layout based on some keys you type. Unfortunatelly, I am not aware of such tool that could be run in a regular Ubuntu install.

Comment: How can I know which layout this keyboard has? On manual or keyboard box there is no information.

Comment: There is an autodetect tool in the installer. Unfortunatelly, I do not know of such tool you could run in a regular Ubuntu install.

Comment: There is no installer CD with the keyboard; it's just plug and play.
EDIT: and there is no driver on TECKNET webiste

Comment: There is in the Ubuntu installer. Keyboard layout is *never* plug and play.

Comment: Ok, however you are talking about a hidden process that I can't access easily. It's something that is related to the OS.

Comment: @Kowak No, really, it's quite simple and your problem isn't even related to a specific layout but with having NUM LOCK enabled!!! (yes, it's as ridiculous as it sounds). In this specific keyboard press F11 (use FN+F11 otherwise if you need the usual, software dependent, F11 action) (All FN+something actions are marked in blue). RE: the actual layout, again, you need to select it. In your case you need to select "Italian" obviously. NO OS ON EARTH DO THIS AUTOMATICALLY, and they never could, what's printed in the keys is meaningless unless "translated" by using the layout that matches.

Comment: @ChanganAuto: Good catch to notice the numlock issue. This is a page which may be helpful: https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/numeric-keypad.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had the same problem. Turns out it is because of the NUM lock being enabled. Had to press all the keys to disable it and now it works!